# Error with stubgen and generic used by mypy-protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, mypy, python-typing, grpc-python

When I use the `protoc-gen-mypy` plugin from [`mypy-protobuf`](https://github.com/nipunn1313/mypy-protobuf) with `protoc` to generate mypy stubs for my gRPC Greeter service, I get an error about generics.

Here is the command I used to generate the `greeter_pb2_grpc.pyi` file:

```bash
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-mypy=`which protoc-gen-mypy` -Iprotos --mypy_grpc_out=grpc protos/greeter.proto
```

Here is the content of `greeter_pb2_grpc.pyi`:

```py
"""
@generated by mypy-protobuf.  Do not edit manually!
isort:skip_file
"""
import abc
import greeter_pb2
import grpc

class GreeterStub:
    """The greeting service definition."""
    def __init__(self, channel: grpc.Channel) -> None: ...
    SayHello: grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable[
        greeter_pb2.HelloRequest,
        greeter_pb2.HelloReply]
    """Sends a greeting"""


class GreeterServicer(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    """The greeting service definition."""
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def SayHello(self,
        request: greeter_pb2.HelloRequest,
        context: grpc.ServicerContext,
    ) -> greeter_pb2.HelloReply:
        """Sends a greeting"""
        pass


def add_GreeterServicer_to_server(servicer: GreeterServicer, server: grpc.Server) -> None: ...
```

When I run `mypy`, I get this error in the `greeter_pb2_grpc.pyi` file:

> "UnaryUnaryMultiCallable" expects no type arguments, but 2 given

The actual definition in the `grpc` library is:

```py
class UnaryUnaryMultiCallable(six.with_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta)): ...
```

So, `stubgen` generates a stub like this:

```py
class UnaryUnaryMultiCallable(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
```

I don't want to edit what `mypy-protobuf` generates because what I usually edit is what `stubgen` generates.

How should I edit the `grpc/__init__.pyi` file that `stubgen` generates to make `mypy` not complain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to generate your own stubs for `grpc` because [`grpc-stubs`](https://github.com/shabbyrobe/grpc-stubs) already does that.

And this library uses this for the class definition (see [here](https://github.com/shabbyrobe/grpc-stubs/blob/85045efc74b345748cff06431a77f7ee68037fd7/grpc-stubs/__init__.pyi#L473)):

```py
class UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor(typing.Generic[TRequest, TResponse]):
```

So, just doing `pip install grpc-stubs` and removing your `grpc/**/*.pyi` stubs for `grpc` should do the trick.

---

The above is a good solution if you are not using `grpc.aio`.

However, if you use `grpc.aio` and have, for instance, a class inheriting from a `grpc.aio.ServerInterceptor` like this:

```py
class LoggingInterceptor(grpc.aio.ServerInterceptor):
```

Because of this [`grpc-stubs` issue](https://github.com/shabbyrobe/grpc-stubs/issues/22), you'll need to do something more manual.

I personally had to create my own stubs from scratch (with the help of `stubgen`) because I couldn't find a way to merge custom stubs with stubs coming from `grpc-stubs` (like how [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) would work in TypeScript).

Don't uninstall `grpc-stubs` because you'll still need it to have types for `grpc_health` and `grpc_reflection`.

I'm not including what I did in this StackOverflow answer because it is only has a partial coverage of `grpc` and `grpc.aio` and it depends on my server code.